# Obstacle avoidance using a monocular camera

Tags: ros, monocular-camera, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if there is a ROS package for (unknown) obstacle avoidance using a monocular camera.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165711/obstacle-avoidance-using-a-monocular-camera/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't seen any research papers that claim to do this, let alone a polished ROS package for it.

I suspect this is still a research topic in computer vision.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-19**:
Thanks a lot for the insight :-)